# Scrape Table Data from Website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape table data from a website using BeautifulSoup4 and Python then creating an Excel document with the results.  So far, I have this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://opl.tmhp.com/ProviderManager/SearchResults.aspx?TPI=&OfficeHrs=4&ProgType=STAR&UCCIndicator=No+Preference&Cnty=&NPI=&Srvs=6&Age=All&Gndr=B&SortBy=Distance&ZipCd=78552&SrvsOfrd=0&SpecCd=0&Name=&CntySrvd=0&Plan=H3&WvrProg=0&SubSpecCd=0&AcptPnt=Y&Rad=200&LangCd=99').read())

for row in soup('table', {'class' : 'spad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

But it isn't working to display the data.

Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't see a class 'spad' on that page - are you sure it's correct?

Answer (score 5):

First of all the class is `StandardResultsGrid`, not `spad`.

Second, you don't need the `tbody` thing. Simply use:

```
for row in soup('table', {'class' : 'StandardResultsGrid'})[0]('tr'):
```

Also note, that since in the 
original page the row with header is included in `tbody` for some reason, you'll have to skip the first row, so

```
for row in soup('table', {'class' : 'StandardResultsGrid'})[0]('tr')[1:]
```

And note that some cells include `table`s in them, so you'll have to parse the contents of the `td`s carefully.